# Replace '\t' with the correct amount of spaces inside a text object

Tags: matlab, text, textbox, matlab-figure, spacing

I have a text box in my GUI, into which I want to write a tabbed text.

As you may or may not know, the `\t` modifier does not work in a tex-interpreted text strings.

What I ask is if there's an elegant solution to emulate the tab modifier with the CORRECT amount of spaces, also taking into account the fact that different characters might have different widths?

Result should be like this:

```
[tabText('Try\tThis') ; tabText(Tryy\tThis)]

ans = 
Try     This
Tryy    This
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`'\t'` in matlab is interpreted as it is: two characters `\` and `t`, not the tabulation.

To obtain the tabulation character, you'll have to go through [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
> 'Try\tThis'
Try\tThis
> sprintf('Try\tThis')
Try       This
```

Or with `char(9)` (ASCII code):

```
> ['Try' char(9) 'This']
Try       This
```

Comment: This works to some extent, but not to my intended end... what I have is a text box in my GUI, into which I want to write a tabbed text. char(9) does provide the tabulation when I set the string.

Comment: @YuvalWeissler Have a look at [this contribution](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10536-detab--a-pedestrian-string-detabulator).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the relevant part of the MATLAB documentation for [`text`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave) (at the time of writing, this points to the R2016b docs) one can see the TeX "subset" that is supported by MATLAB, and it **does not include any tab-like character**. Thus it seems that there's no *proper* way to do this with the `tex` interpreter.

You have several options:

1. If using `uifigures` is an option, text labels there allow MathML to be used. Which is very customizable...
2. If you switch to the `'latex'` interpreter, you could use `\quad`, `\qquad` etc.

   ```
    figure(); 
    text(.5,.5,{'$$This \quad text$$','$$is \quad properly$$','$$tabbed, \quad Right?$$'},...
      'Interpreter','latex');
   ```
3. [What O'Neil suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42548738/3372061).

Regarding the unequal character width - you might be able to overcome this by changing the font, using the 'FontName' argument to `text(...)`.